# Dim horizontal lines in PC LED monitor when any external active device is added and activated

Tags: multiple-monitors, power-supply, line-spacing, logitech-speakers

e.g. 2nd led monitors or external active speakers do that. It's not disturbing but I'm worried that it may cause damage to any of the devices.

Double-checked all internal and external wiring and all looks seated.

And yes, the lines occur even while the PC is in BIOS setup.

It sounds like an electrical issue to me but I don't know where to start.

Appreciate any guidelines.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are the speakers added through the monitor or when you add the items through the monitor? What color are the lines?  How many lines?  Are they all the way through the monitor?

Comment: Speakers are active and connected to PC's audio out. The lines are white colored.